# Introducing delay to Microsoft bot for use with Cortana to accept input

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding, cortana

I am building a microsoft bot using LUIS that I want to use as a cortana skill. What I want to do is to fake an activity that takes place in the background and introduce some delay (about 10 seconds or so), during which the user can optionally manually ask a question. If however there is no interruption during the delay, I would like it to display a message and then accept input automatically. Does anyone have any ideas how to implement that?

Comment: Please start with something and provide a [MCVE] in order to get help. Refer to tutorials and samples online, there's a lot of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you’d like to send [proactive messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-proactive-messages) to user when the delay time that you specified arrives, and connect the bot to Cortana channel. As far as I know, at the moment, it does not yet support proactive messages in Cortana channel.

For more information, you can check and track this feature request:[Proactive messages support for Cortana Skills](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2933).